# Where do "name" and "type" attributes come from in xsd:element declarations?

Tags: xml, xsd

Although I have worked on XML Schema, I still have some doubts:

The below is sample XML Schema (from w3schools):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Where do the "name" and "type" attributes come from? In this XSD we are defining the elements which can appear in an XML document.

Most of the elements/constructs in XSD we prefix.  For example: `xs:element`, `xs:complexType` and so on.  Where do "name" and "type" come from?

Any clarification appreciated.

Comment: That's how schema is defined. Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp)

Comment: what i am asking is, are "name" , "type"  part of some namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` and `type` attributes on an `xs:element` declaration in XML Schema come from the [W3C XML Schema Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Element_Declaration_details) and are used to define the name and type, respectively, of the element being declared.

They do not have a namespace prefix (`xs:`) because they are not defined to be in a namespace.  This is as designed.  It would be an error to use `xs:name` or `xs:type`.